# IIS Url Rewrite Rule

Tags: iis-7, url-rewriting

I am new to Url rewrite rules so any help would be gratefully appreciated.

Looking to create a IIS Url rewrite that will handle any of the following

```
http://localhost/homepage/contact-us.aspx -> http://localhost/contact-us.aspx
http://localhost/homepage/about-us.aspx -> http://localhost/about-us.aspx
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this but I think you would have something like this in your web.config file.

You can edit the web.config file and then go into IIS and the rule should show up if you want to test it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="rewriterule1" enabled="true" stopProcessing="false">
                    <match url="homepage/(.*)" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="http://localhost/{R:1}" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```